# How to find highest product of k elements in an array of n length, where k < n

Tags: python, data-structures

I recently tried the question for the highest product of 3 elements. Now I am trying to do it for the k elements. Let's say from 3 now it is asking for 4 elements. I tried to write a generic function so it could handle for any k elements within the array. The algo has to be in O(n) just like the one with 3 elements is.

```
 def highest_product_sol(input):

    high = max(input[0],input[1])
    low = min(input[0],input[1])


    max_prod_2 = input[0] * input[1]
    low_prod_2 = input[0] * input[1]
    max_prod_3 = max_prod_2 * input[2]


    prod_2_high = input[0] * input[1]
    prod_2_low = input[0] * input[1]

    for i in range(2,len(input)):
        val = input[i]
        max_prod_3 = max(max_prod_3,max_prod_2*val,low_prod_2*val)

        prod_2_high = high * val
        prod_2_low =  low * val

        max_prod_2 = max(max_prod_2,prod_2_high)

        low_prod_2 = min(low_prod_2,prod_2_high)


        high = max(high,val)

        low = min(low,val)


    return (max_prod_2,low_prod_2,max_prod_3)

def highest_product_num(input,num):


    high = max(input[0:num - 1])
    low = min(input[0:num - 1])


    print("max",high)
    print("min",low)

    prod_high_minus_1 = 1
    prod_low_minus_1 = 1

    for n in range(0,num-1):
        prod_high_minus_1 *= input[n]
        prod_low_minus_1 *= input[n]

    max_prod_n_1 = prod_high_minus_1
    min_prod_n_1 = prod_high_minus_1
    max_prod_n = prod_high_minus_1 * input[num-1]

    for i in range(num,len(input)):
        val = input[i]
        max_prod_n = max(max_prod_n,max_prod_n_1*val,min_prod_n_1*val)

        prod_high_minus_1 = high * val
        prod_low_minus_1 =  low * val

        max_prod_n_1 = max(max_prod_n_1,prod_high_minus_1)

        min_prod_n_1 = min(min_prod_n_1,prod_low_minus_1)


        high = max(high,val)

        low = min(low,val)

    return max_prod_n
test_input = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,-2,3,4,5,100,2,3,1],[-10,-10,1,3,2][1000,7,-6,2,2]]
print(test_input)

for i in test_input:
    print(highest_product_num(i,4),"\n")

# correct `results`
# 1680
# 6000
# 600
```

Comment: numpy acceptable?

Comment: Where is this problem from? I have a feeling you're still not telling us everything or you're misrepresenting something. I'd like to see the original problem description.

Comment: I don't believe O(n) is possible for arbitrary k; I have no proof, but I would estimate a minimum bound of O(n log min(k, n - k)) or worse.

Comment: @ephemient I think O(n + klogk) is doable. Find the largest k numbers in O(n) and sort them in O(klogk), find the smallest k numbers in O(n) and sort them in O(klogk), then merge those two parts in O(k). Just haven't fully thought through the merging...

Comment: @StefanPochmann Hmm, okay possibly - I was using the middle case of k = n / 2 to check my intuition, but when k = n - k = O(n) both our guesses come out to O(n log n).

Comment: @ephemient Yeah I'm still not sure how our complexity classes compare overall. But if you take the "geometric middle", i.e., k=sqrt(n), then my class is O(n) while yours is still O(n log n). Anyway, an idea for the merging: Assume that it's best to take the largest k numbers. So multiply all of them. Then try replacing pairs of the smallest large numbers with pairs of smallest small (i.e., the two "most negative") numbers.

Comment: @StefanPochmann you needn't sort the k highest.

Comment: The problem looks difficult so how about write algorithm for k = 3. The one I wrote for 3 how would you write for 4 not using the algo which is there for k = 3.

Comment: @D.J Why keep the source of this problem secret?

Comment: @StefanPochmann lol I am not keeping it a secret. It is an interview question from GeeksforGeeks and interview cake.

Comment: @D.J Well you **were** keeping it secret, not telling us even after I had asked for it and explained why I did. And you're still pretty much keeping it secret, telling us website names instead of giving us links to the problem. Why? I'm pretty sure you're misrepresenting the problem, but I can't tell for sure unless I see the original.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Here you go https://www.interviewcake.com/question/python/highest-product-of-3 

What I am asking is modified version of question I want to first learn how solve it for 4 elements.  Once I learned that I want to apply same technique for k elements.

Comment: @D.J The only time I see the k version mentioned there is as the second bonus question *"What if we wanted the highest product of k items?"* but that doesn't say it must be O(n). Am I overlooking something, or did you make that up?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I want to solve the bonus. I made the rule up. I can solve it in nlogn but curious if it could be done in O(n)

Answer (score 3):

O(n) solution in `numpy`, stress-tested on the 4 example lists and @Stefan Pochmann's merciless auto test script. Big thanks to Stefan, without whose input a couple of severe bugs would have gone unnoticed.

```
import numpy as np

def kmaxprod_v2(data, k):
    if len(data) < k:
        return np.nan
    data = np.asanyarray(data)
    # for integer dtypes convert to python ints to have unlimited range for the
    # final product
    dfp = data.astype(object) if data.dtype in (
        int, np.int64, np.int32, np.int16, np.int8) else data
    # np.argpartition raises an exception if len(data) == k, therefore
    if len(data) == k:
        return np.prod(dfp)
    neg = data <= 0
    # if k is odd and there are no positive elements we must settle for the
    # least negative
    if k % 2 == 1 and np.count_nonzero(neg) == len(data):
        return np.prod(-np.partition(-data, k)[:k].astype(dfp.dtype))
    # now n > k and we have at least one positive element
    ap = np.argpartition(-np.absolute(data), k)
    low, high = ap[k:], ap[:k]
    # try multiplying the k with highest absolute value
    greedy = np.prod(dfp[high])
    if greedy >= 0:
        return greedy
    # there are two possible ways of fixing the sign:
    # either swap the worst negative inside for the best positive outside
    # or swap the worst positive inside for the best negative outside
    # compute both and compare
    # bpo in, wni out
    bpo = np.max(dfp[low])
    if bpo <= 0:
        spfn = 0
    else:
        neg_high = np.where(neg[high])[0]
        wni_ind = np.argmax(data[high[neg_high]])
        # translate to index in high
        wni_ind = neg_high[wni_ind]
        spfn = bpo*np.prod(dfp[high[:wni_ind]])*np.prod(dfp[high[wni_ind+1:]])
    # bno in, wno out
    pos_high = np.where(~neg[high])[0]
    if len(pos_high) == 0:
        snfp = 0
    else:
        wpi_ind = np.argmin(data[high[pos_high]])
        wpi_ind = pos_high[wpi_ind]
        bno = np.min(dfp[low])
        snfp = bno*np.prod(dfp[high[:wpi_ind]])*np.prod(dfp[high[wpi_ind+1:]])
    return max(spfn, snfp)
```

Brief description of algo:

- special case k odd, all data negative find k least negative by partition, return prod, stop
- partition by absolute value, splitting at rank k - O(n) worstcase with introselect library function
- if prod top k >= 0, stop
- if possible swap least positive inside for most negative outside, store prod
- if possible swap least negative inside for most positive outside, store prod
- return best of above, stop

Sample run:

```
>>> test_input = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,-2,3,4,5,100,2,3,1],[-10,-10,1,3,2],[1000,7,-6,2,2]]
>>> for t in test_input:
...     kmp.kmaxprod(t,4)
... 
1680
6000
600
28000
```

Test script, thanks @Stefan Pochmann

```
import itertools, operator, functools, time
def naive(data, k):
    return max(functools.reduce(operator.mul, comb) for comb in itertools.combinations(data, k))

test_input = [([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 4), ([1,-2,3,4,5,100,2,3,1], 4),
              ([-10,-10,1,3,2], 4), ([1000,7,-6,2,2],4),
              ([-1, 0, 1], 2), ([2, 5, 8, 9, 1, 3, 7], 4),
              ([-1, -1, 2, 1], 2), ([-1000, -1, 2, 3], 2),
              ([3, 5, 2, 8, 3], 2), ([-1000, -1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 2)]

for t, k in test_input:
    print(t, k, kmaxprod_v2(t, k), naive(t, k))

ne = 0
t = np.zeros((3,))
import random
for k in range(2, 20):
  for n in range(k, 24):
    print('n =', n, ': k =', k, 'errors:', ne, 'total time O(n), naive:', np.diff(t))
    for _ in range(100):
        data = [random.randrange(-14, 15) for _ in range(n)]
        t[0] += time.time()
        a = kmaxprod_v2(data, k)
        t[1] += time.time()
        b = naive(data, k)
        t[2] += time.time()
        if a != b:
            ne += 1
            print(data, k, a, b)
```

Comment: Comments [archived in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135462/discussion-on-answer-by-paul-panzer-how-to-find-highest-product-of-k-elements-in).

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def get_largest_product(l,n):
    possible_products = [reduce(operator.mul,c,1) for c in combinations(l, n)]
    return max(possible_products)

print (get_largest_product([232,434,5,4],3))
```

Output:

```
503440
```

Comment: Good idea, but not necessarily correct if some numbers are negative.

Comment: @ephemient Just realised the problem. Gonna try it now.

Comment: @ephemient Thanks. it has to be in O(n).

Comment: @D.J you will need a heuristic algorithm for this.

Comment: @AlexFung How would do it without reducing. and combinations.